# Good tutorial for security on a server

Tags: security, hacking

I previously have had trouble with hackers hacking into servers I was using for web hosting. Does anyone know any good tutorials to prevent it, or perhaps give me some tips on how to increase security? I'm colocating a server soon, so I don't want the same thing happening again. Thanks for the help! :)

EDIT: Or would it be best to hire a professional to secure the server?

Comment: Definitively hire a professional.

Comment: Yeah. Thought that would be best, as I don't know much about security so a tutorial wouldn't help really and would be far too risky. Do you know any decent sites that provide security services? :)

Comment: In Japan, Singapore or the Bermudas? An expert has to be near to you. So that you can phone him in an emergency and he will be there in a few hours. I can recommend http://heinlein-support.de/ but maybe they are too far away from you.

Comment: Yeah. I'm in the UK. No worries I'll ask around and do some searches for a good company. Thanks for the help mailq! :)

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com for learning more about security. Also, there are a few consultants from the UK there that would be able to help outside of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just leave this here, in case someone finds this post and would like to get a start on server security:
[nsa guides for sever setup](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/guidance/security_configuration_guides/current_guides.shtml). I would start with the linux server config guide.